# Why does this half-bridge mosfet not short to ground?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

Please take a look at this circuit, which I am using purely as an example:
[image: Half bridge driver circuit]

Please can someone explain why, if a battery was attached, does the circuit not short to ground as I drew in the red arrow?

Surely, if and when the "low" side is on, and the "high" side (HIDRV) mosfet off, then there is a short to ground?

Comment: Q2 is only conducting as long as L is “blocking” as in current in flowing to the right side in normal operation. (Save for special cases like forced CCM). Look up the term free wheeling diode. Q2 is a lower loss version of it.

Comment: There is. So, basically, the chip won't do that. It will switch the FETs at high frequency ... a high enough frequency that the inductor's impedance is high - and thus, not a short circuit.

Comment: Ah OK. so there will not be a situation where the Low is on and the Hi is off for a long period of time-at any stage? Let me rephrase, so if the above chip wants to stop charging completely it will turn both Hi and Low off?

Comment: Thanks guys, how do I mark your answers as the answers? Much obliged!

Comment: It's actually a very good question, because if the chip ever did that it would be a disaster. It wont' normally happen; but it could turn some kinds of failure modes into a much bigger problem. In a high reliability design you WOULD have to consider that sort of case and mitigate against it (e.g. fuse the battery line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1 and Q2 are a pair driving an inductor to form a buck (step-down) DC-DC converter.

There are two phases of operation:

- Q1 on: current flows into the inductor L and load, meanwhile the inductor stores energy (builds flux)
- Q2 on: inductor L energy released, current flows into load as the flux collapses

The key is, neither Q1 or Q2 are kept on long enough such that a short can occur; the current though L is a sawtwooth that averages out to the charging current being delivered to the load. This is true so long as Q1, Q2 and the bq24650 IC are working correctly to deliver the charge current.

That said, you're right in observing that if Q2 stayed on, the battery would be connected as a short-circuit through the inductor L. That's not likely as the IC controls the Q2 gate, but it's a possible failure mode to consider.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think is the job of the bq24650, here ;)?

It switches Q1 (and Q2) on and off in a manner that employs L as the energy storage of a switch-mode power supply (a term that you should research; explaining SMPS here would definitely be out of scope).

So, Q1 will never be switched on for long enough for current that you don't want to (effectively) flow to flow to ground.

From the view of the battery, this will look like a higher voltage feeding *into* the battery, or a high-impedance "block".